# How to prove coercivity

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods, convex-analysis

I have a problem in understanding how to prove if a function is positive or negative coercive. I understood the definition of coercivity, which is: $$\lim_{||x|| \to +\infty}f(x) = +\infty$$

However, I do not get how to apply this definition. For example, given:

$f(x_{1},x_{2})=x_{1}^2+2x_{1}+x_{2}^2-3x_{2}-2$

and

$f(x_{1},x_{2})=x_{1}^3-x_{1}^4+x_{1}x_{2}-x_{2}^2$

how can it be shown that these two function are coercive or not?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have missed an index in the definition of your first function?

Comment: Might it help switching to polar coordinates and considering the limit as $r \rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general rule, and you must carefully analyse the function. The first function is
$$
f(x_1,x_2) = \|(x_1,x_2)\|^2 +2x_1 -3x_2 -2
$$
and it is coercive because the term $2x_1 -3x_2 -2$ grows linearly at infinity.

The second example is not coercive, since
$$
f(0,x_2) = -x_2^2 \to -\infty
$$
when $|x_2| \to +\infty$